# Pycharm and FEniCS

Tags: python, pycharm, fenics

I have installed Fenics using this

https://fenics.readthedocs.io/projects/containers/en/latest/introduction.html#running-fenics-in-docker

and everything works so far.

Now I wanted to use Pycharm to try to write a program using fenics. It starts with

from fenics import *

and I get the error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fenics'.

I use Python 3.9, PyCharm 2021.1.2.

Can the problem come from some wring directories?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've installed fenics on your local machine, as well as added it to your Pycharm package library.

https://fenics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: I have now added the package to the library (added a picture to the original question) but the error remains. What do you mean by "installed fenics on your local machine"?

Comment: Yup, so with https://fenics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html for example, if you use Python3, to open up the terminal in that area, and install the package with pip3 or whatever you prefer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your comment or what it's referring to.